# How to check for an empty string in MyBatis?

Tags: mybatis

How do I check for an empty string in the dynamic SQL of MyBatis? I find the code below in the documentaiton, but I want to check for empty string, not null.

```xml
<select id="findActiveBlogWithTitleLike" parameterType="Blog" resultType="Blog">
    SELECT * FROM BLOG WHERE state = ‘ACTIVE’
    <if test="title != null">
        AND title like #{title}
    </if>
</select>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In MyBatis you can use `!= ''` to compare with empty string, so in your query it would be something like:

```xml
<select id="findActiveBlogWithTitleLike" parameterType="Blog" resultType="Blog">
  SELECT * FROM BLOG WHERE state = ‘ACTIVE’
  <if test="title != null and title != ''">
    AND title like #{title}
  </if>
</select>
```

Comment: how about this? "title.length() > 0".

Comment: @X.Chen That will throw `NullPointException` if `title` is `null`

Comment: "title != ''" don't work if the title = 0. With Long value you only need "title != null".

Answer (score 6):

Dont't speak English well. Thank you for your patient.

It's functions xml file.

```
<mapper namespace="org.jacknie.mybatis.Functions">
  <sql id="isBlank">
    <bind name="isBlank" value=":[@org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils@isBlank(#this)]" />
  </sql>
  <sql id="sysout">
    <bind name="sysout" value=":[@System@out.println(#this)]" />
  </sql>
</mapper>
```

It's mapper xml file.

```
<mapper namespace="org.jacknie.test.TestMapper">
  <select id="selectTest" resultType="_int">
    <include refid="org.jacknie.mybatis.Functions.isBlank" />
    <include refid="org.jacknie.mybatis.Functions.sysout" />
    SELECT '1' FROM DUAL
    <if test="#fn = isBlank, not(#fn(map.name))">
      <bind name="forLogging" value="#fn = sysout, #fn('Hello' + map.name)" />
    </if>
  </select>
</mapper>
```

How about think this tip...

[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/jacknieKorean/3f51046d1a53a86a549a4994ff4f0a8c)